# Check formatting with java

Tags: java, string, format

I have a certain set of data that has a very certain spacing that goes along with it. I was wondering if there would be anyway to scan that file with Java, check for any line that has two spaces before it and store that in an array. I'm not sure on how to check the lines to see if the line begins with two spaces verses anything else. And if it does I would like to store that string in an array like I said earlier. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: `if(string.substring(0, 2).equals("  ")){/*do mah shit*/}`

Comment: @thatidiotguy: there's the easier `startsWith()` method (edit: nevermind about 1 space instead of 2 spaces; comment editor is shrinking 2 spaces into one, so that wasn't your fault)

Comment: @BalusC I think it is pretty obviously supposed to be 2 spaces as per question. No need to fuss over editor weirdness.

Comment: Or `"  linetocompare".startsWith("  ")`

Comment: Test: `string.startsWith("  ")`. @thatidiotguy: sorry, I take my words back. It's indeed the editor.

Comment: I didn't realize there was startsWith function. That helps a lot...

Comment: The problem I'm facing now is that all lines begin with either two or four spaces, and I want to only grab the ones with two. Since they all technically begin with two spaces this doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read in a line from the file
2. Check the first two characters of that line for spaces
3. If there are two spaces, use a `StringTokenizer` to split up the string into words, and store it in an array, or however you want to do it...

Comment: Can i check both spaces at once, or will i need to substring each space and check if it equals " "?

Comment: Look at the comments on your question.. there are options for you there. This is the logic you need to follow